# pip install string error

Tags: python, pip, module

I am trying to install "string" and "name" on my terminal using pip.
Every time I do so I keep getting this error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for random

and

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement string (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for string

If anyone knows a solution please let me know, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to install core python libraries? You should already have access to them (though I don't know about `name`)

Comment: Im trying to run a python program that generates .xlsx files. I need libraries string, random, name, and xlwt. I also thought these libraries already came installed but doesn't seem the case. to run the program i need all four libraries but i only got 2 name and xlwt

Comment: What makes you think the libraries are not already installed? also, what suggests you need those four libraries? does the program come with an associated `requirements.txt` file of required libraries? are those imports listed in the script header? Lastly, might consider reinstalling python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `random` and `string` modules come pre-installed with most Python installations. You should be able to perform the following without the need for 'pip':

```
$ python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar  1, 2018, 18:36:50)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> import string
```

Answer (score -1):

**ERROR:** Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random

**ERROR:** No matching distribution found for random

if the above one is your error

then follow these steps-

Press

**ctrl+f**

**In the following website,to search module** [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs)

**NOTE**- check your python version before installing any module

After installing module copy and paste in your pip folder.

follow this path to paste your module in pip folder.

[C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts]

**HOPE IT HELPS!**